# Transparent Layers in one JFrame 

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jframe, translucency

I need to put three images one over the other, but i need to see through each one, as if they were transparent. 
It's not working .
(i'm using , netbeans)

Comment: "It's not working" doesn't tell us anything about what error or behavior you're seeing that you don't want. Without posting the relevant parts of your code, and describing _precisely_ what is not working and how it's not working, you probably won't get any help.

Answer (score 3):

not clear from your question, but there are two areas, but no one from them has to do something with NetBeans.

There should not be a coincidence to the IDE.

1) [How to Decorate Components with the JLayer Class](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/jlayer.html)

2) [How to Create Translucent and Shaped Windows](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/trans_shaped_windows.html)

3) maybe with [OverlayLayout](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/1401__OverlayLayout.htm)